# AngularJS - Using ng-repeat to create sets of radio inputs

Tags: angularjs

I'm evaluating angularjs for a future project. One of the things I will need to do is display different pages of "channel" information by selecting an appropriate "page" radio input. Furthermore, ranges of page buttons may also be selected from a group of "page set" radio inputs.

The working example below has a set of 32 channels with the visible group of channels being selected via a combination of "set" and "page" radio inputs, giving a total of 2 * 4 pages of 4 channels each.

```
<!doctype html>
<html ng-app>
  <head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="angular.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      function Channels($scope) {
        $scope.groupSize = 4;
        $scope.pageSet = 0;
        $scope.pageNumber = 0;
        $scope.channels = [
          {"id": "Ch-001"}, {"id": "Ch-002"}, {"id": "Ch-003"}, {"id": "Ch-004"},
          {"id": "Ch-005"}, {"id": "Ch-006"}, {"id": "Ch-007"}, {"id": "Ch-008"},
          {"id": "Ch-009"}, {"id": "Ch-010"}, {"id": "Ch-011"}, {"id": "Ch-012"},
          {"id": "Ch-013"}, {"id": "Ch-014"}, {"id": "Ch-015"}, {"id": "Ch-016"},
          {"id": "Ch-017"}, {"id": "Ch-018"}, {"id": "Ch-019"}, {"id": "Ch-020"},
          {"id": "Ch-021"}, {"id": "Ch-022"}, {"id": "Ch-023"}, {"id": "Ch-024"},
          {"id": "Ch-025"}, {"id": "Ch-026"}, {"id": "Ch-027"}, {"id": "Ch-028"},
          {"id": "Ch-029"}, {"id": "Ch-030"}, {"id": "Ch-031"}, {"id": "Ch-032"}
        ];
      }
    </script>
  </head>

  <body ng-controller="Channels">
    <p>Set:
      <input type="radio" name="pageSet" ng-model="pageSet" ng-value="0">1-4</input>
      <input type="radio" name="pageSet" ng-model="pageSet" ng-value="1">5-8</input>
    </p>
    <p>Page:
      <input type="radio" name="pageNumber" ng-model="pageNumber" ng-value="0">{{pageSet * groupSize + 1}}</input>
      <input type="radio" name="pageNumber" ng-model="pageNumber" ng-value="1">{{pageSet * groupSize + 2}}</input>
      <input type="radio" name="pageNumber" ng-model="pageNumber" ng-value="2">{{pageSet * groupSize + 3}}</input>
      <input type="radio" name="pageNumber" ng-model="pageNumber" ng-value="3">{{pageSet * groupSize + 4}}</input>
    </p>
    <ul>
      <li ng-repeat="channel in channels | limitTo: groupSize * ((groupSize * pageSet) + pageNumber + 1) | limitTo: -groupSize">
        <p>{{channel.id}}</p>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </body>
</html>
```

My question is how to create the page/page set radio inputs using `ng-repeat`. I've tried approaches such as:

```
<p>Set: <input ng-repeat="n in [0,1]" type="radio" name="pageSet" ng-model="pageSet" ng-value="{{n}}"></p>
<p>Page: <input ng-repeat="n in [0,1,2,3]" type="radio" name="pageNumber" ng-model="pageNumber" ng-value="{{n}}"></p>
```

which looks right, but the values don't bind to the corresponding pageSet/pageNumber variables. Can anyone tell what I'm missing here?

Answer (score 177, accepted):

ng-repeat create a child scope, so you have to bind to the $parent:

Here's a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/g/r9MLe/2/

Sample:

```
  <p>Set:
         <label ng-repeat="n in [0,1]">
       <input type="radio" name="pageSet" ng-model="$parent.pageSet" ng-value="n" />{{n}}
         </label>
     </p>
     <p>Page: 
         <label ng-repeat="n in [0,1,2,3]">
         <input type="radio" name="pageNumber" ng-model="$parent.pageNumber" ng-value="n" /> {{n}}
         </label>
     </p>
```

Comment: No problem, another workaround is to use a nested property, like pager.pageSet and pager.pageNumber for exemple, with the javascript prototypal inheritance it would modify the object on the $parent scope.

Comment: Nice, thanks. I actually chose to put the pager variables under a separate controller so that I could duplicate the functionality and share the channel data.

Comment: if you're using Ionic framework, you need to use $parent.$parent as $parent points to scroll object.

Answer (score 6):

What's wrong with just using a value from the JSON?

```
       <table>
          <tr ng-repeat="v in partneradd.verifications">
            <td>{{v.label}}</td>
            <td>
              <div class="radio-inline">
                <label>
                  <input type="radio" name="{{v.value}}" value="required"> Required
                </label>
              </div>
            </td>
            <td>
              <div class="radio-inline">
                <label>
                  <input type="radio" name="{{v.value}}" value="optional"> Optional
                </label>
              </div>
            </td>
          </tr>
        </table>
```

from the data:

```
vm.verifications = [
{
  "label" : "Valid last line (USPS only)",
  "value" : "vll",
  "type" : "optional"
},
{
  "label" : "Domestic recipient",
  "value" : "dr",
  "type" : "optional"
},
];
```

Answer (score 3):

This is simple example. Hope everything is clear.

Parameter `name` is mandatory in radio button (for ability check one button from group).

Html:

```
<form name="myForm" ng-controller="MyCtrl">
    <p>Favorite Beatle</p>
    <ul>
        <li ng-repeat="person in people">
            <label>
                <input type="radio" ng-model="$parent.name" name="name" value="{{person.name}}" required />{{person.name}}
            </label>
        </li>
    </ul>
    <p><tt>myForm.$invalid: {{myForm.$invalid}}</tt></p>
    <button ng-disabled="myForm.$invalid">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Javascript:

```
function MyCtrl($scope) {
    $scope.people = [{
        name: "John"
    }, {
        name: "Paul"
    }, {
        name: "George"
    }, {
        name: "Ringo"
    }];
}
```