# AngularJS ng-model data from radio button

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have a short form in AngularJS .
I use [`ng-repeat`](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive%3angRepeat) to show genders and validate their radio buttons
The problem is that I want to get the value of the radio button selected and print this out using `ng-model`.
How can achieve this?

[Here Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/2Ec2BzPMZI3mc2ulk834?p=preview)

Comment: Possible duplicated: [AngularJS - Using ng-repeat to create sets of radio inputs](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14775981/angularjs-using-ng-repeat-to-create-sets-of-radio-inputs)

Comment: All the solutions are stopping the validation! pls help

Comment: it s not a duplicate cos I have validation I want to keep and the other question doesn't!

Comment: ok got it now was simple ng-show="user.selectedGender == 1"> and set variable to 1

Answer (score 8):

The problem is you're binding selected gender, a primitive value, to your $scope. When you use ng-repeat it creates a new scope and inherits the values from it's parent. Unfortunately, because your values are primitive (a number), they are passed by value instead of reference, so you only get one way binding. This is why it's **always** recommended to store values on an object in scope instead of directly.

Here's a link to a working controller: http://plnkr.co/edit/Y7sTEaYMx0aD4fPDHAMA?p=preview

I added this, and adjusted the rest of the code accordingly:

```
$scope.user = {
    selectedGender: 'none'
}
```

Comment: All the solutions are stopping the validation! pls help

Comment: @AlexG_1010100101 That's a separate question. It's also to do with ng-repeat though. Your form is getting confused because it's trying to validate multiple elements with the same name. Read this article, it'll show you how to use ngForm to make it work: http://blog.brunoscopelliti.com/the-ngform-directive-of-angularjs

Answer (score 1):

The solution by Mike Robinson is the most elegant. However, a quick fix is to add $parent:

```
            <input type="radio" ng-model="$parent.selectedGender" name="radiob" id="{{g.id}}" value="{{g.id}}" required />{{g.name}}
```

This will change the selectGender in the parent scope of the ng-repeat.

http://plnkr.co/edit/M5cos7xFBA9a0eRWhHi9?p=info